# How to apply damage to another player with Mirror Network (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I am working on 3D multiplayer game with Mirror Engine and looking for the solution of following issues:
I have a prefab "Vampire" which is spawned on server by different clients. When one vampire collides (OnTriggerEnter) with another, I want second one to be damaged...

I have methods at the same class:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer) return;

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().CmdApplyDamage();
    }
}
```

and

```
[Command]
public void CmdApplyDamage()
{
   this.healthPoints--;
}
```

OnTriggerEnter() works fine but CmdApplyDamage() is not called

Comment: in general your tag check is redundant .. simply use `if(other.TryGetComponnet<Player>(out var player)){ player.CmdApplyDamage(); }`

Comment: And in general: Wouldn't both vampires be a local player on their according local device -> they would hurt each other

Comment: @derHugo would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest debugging with log messages and/or breakpoints to check at which point a condition is not met